# Understanding the CAN filters

Tags: stm32, can-bus, stm32f4discovery

I am unable to understand the CAN filter configuration for the stm32f4-discovery.

```
CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterNumber = 0;
CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterMode = CAN_FilterMode_IdMask;
CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterScale = CAN_FilterScale_32bit;
CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterIdHigh = 0x0000;
CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterIdLow = 0x0000;
CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x0000;
CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;
CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterFIFOAssignment = 0;
CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterActivation = ENABLE;
CAN_FilterInit(&CAN_FilterInitStructure);
```

could some one explain to me how this works? or is it documented in any place? I am unable to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as documentation goes:

[Reference Manual](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/DM00031020.pdf), section 32 bxCAN

[Std Peripheral Lib for F4](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM147/CL1794/SC961/SS1743/PF257901#), has a compiled version of the doxygen documentaion as CHM (stm32f4xx_dsp_stdperiph_lib_um.chm) in the zip file.