# stm32f4 bxCAN in identifier list mode

Tags: microcontroller, stm32f4discovery, can-bus

Can anyone give me an example of how to use CAN acceptance filter in Identifier list mode. I know the list mode works by  directly comparing the ID received with the one in the filter. But I need a code snippet.

I am using this and it is not working

```
CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterNumber = 0;
CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterMode = CAN_FilterMode_IdList;
CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterScale = CAN_FilterScale_16bit;
CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterIdHigh = 0x0000;
CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterIdLow = 0x0127;
CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x0000;
CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;
CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterFIFOAssignment = 0;
CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterActivation = ENABLE;
```

It does not accept any message.

Comment: You are missing on Filter Mask... Make them all 1s i.e. 0xFFFF and check!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding the CAN filters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363197/understanding-the-can-filters)